# Basic Calculations using Javascript for Holiday Booking System

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

************************************** EDIT *************************************

HERE IS LINK TO JSFIDDLE TO MAKE IT EASIER TO ANALYSE WHAT I'M TRYING TO RESOLVE

http://jsfiddle.net/Kaleidoscar/ZEd5V/

---

I have a college assignment to complete which requires me to calculate the price of a hotel and multiply it by the number of days plus any extras to be added to the price of the hotel.

Unfortunately, the code I've provided doesn't work and I'm not sure how I can multiply the hotel price with the holiday duration...  If anyone can help me with this problem, I would gladly appreciate the help.

Here is the html code for my assignment:

HTML

#### Hotels

```
<div class ="HotelBooking">
    <form id="getHotelBooking" onsubmit="return false;">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="radio" id="Miramar" name="selectedhotel" value="Hotel Miramar" />  Hotel Miramar</li> 
            <li><input type="radio" id="Jazminas" name="selectedhotel" value="Las Jazminas" />  Las Jazminas</li>
            <li><input type="radio" id="Tropicana" name="selectedhotel" value="Tropicana Gardens" />  Tropicana Gardens</li>
        </ul> 

          <input type="button" value="OK" class="buttonstyle" onclick="testHotelImages()" />

        <!--INFORMATION ICONS -->               
            <div class="informationWrap">   
                <img src="images/information_italic.png" alt="info" class ="infoIcon" />
                <p class="imgDescription">Please choose from the selection of Hotels provided.  Only 1 hotel can be purchased per hotel booking.  To the left hand-side, a hotel description will appear.  Only press the OK command once you have confirmed your hotel stay.</p>
            </div>

                <img id="PricePlaceHolder" src="images/PricePlaceHolder.jpg" alt="Image gallery" height="150" width="150" /> 

            <div class ="Images">
                 <img id="Hotelplaceholder" src="images/Hotelplaceholder.jpg" alt="Image gallery" height="300" width="615" />        
            </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

#### Options

```
<div class ="HotelBooking">
  <form id="getOptionsBooking" onsubmit="return false;">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="local"  name="check" value="LocalTourOption" /> Tours to Local Interests</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="flyDrive" name="check" value="FlyDriveOption" /> Fly-Drive (have a rental car waiting at the airport)</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="balcony" name="check" value="BalconyOption" /> Balcony</li>
    </ul>
            <p><input type="button" class="buttonstyle" value="OK" onclick="ExtraInterest()" /></p>
```

#### Duration

```
   <form id="FormNights" action="#">
      <p><label for="Nights">Nights:</label>;
         <input type="text" size="10" id="Nights" /> </p>
```

#### Your Party

```
 <form id="Party" action="#">
      <p><label for="Adults">Adults:</label>
         <input type="text" size="2" id="AdultsParty" /> </p>

 <p><input type="button" class="buttonstyle" value="OK" onclick="PartyDetails()" /></p> 

 </form>

    <h3>Your Holiday Summary</h3>
        <div id="TotalCost">  </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var hotel_prices = new Array();
    hotel_prices["Hotel Miramar"] = 50;
    hotel_prices["Las Jazminas"] = 75;
    hotel_prices["Tropicana Gardens"] = 100;

    function getHotelPrice() {
        var HotelSizePrice = 0;          
        var theForm = document.forms["getHotelBooking"];           
        var selectedHotel = theForm.elements["selectedhotel"];

        for (var i = 0; i < selectedHotel.length; i++) {

            if (selectedHotel[i].checked) {                   
                HotelSizePrice = hotel_prices[selectedHotel[i].value];

                break;
            }
        }       
        return HotelSizePrice;


        function LocalExtra() {
            var LocalPrice = 0;             
            var theForm = document.forms["getOptionsBooking"];             
            var includeLocal = theForm.elements["local"];

            if (includeLocal.checked == true) {
                LocalPrice = 60;
            }              
            return LocalPrice;
        }


        function FlyDriveExtra() {
            var FlyDrivePrice = 0;              
            var theForm = document.forms["getOptionsBooking"];             
            var includeFlyDrive = theForm.elements["flyDrive"];

            if (includeFlyDrive.checked == true) {
                FlyDrivePrice = 45;
            }

            return FlyDrivePrice;
        }


        function BalconyExtra() {
            var BalconyPrice = 0;               
            var theForm = document.forms["getOptionsBooking"];            
            var includeBalcony = theForm.elements["balcony"];

            if (includeBalcony.checked == true) {
                BalconyPrice = 30;
            }

            return BalconyPrice;
        }


        function getNights() {               
            var theForm = document.forms["FormNights"];
            var quantity = theForm.elements["Nights"];
            var duration = 0;

            if (quantity.value != "") {
                duration = parseInt(quantity.value);
            }
            return duration;
        }


        function getAdults() {
            var theForm = document.forms["Party"];
            var quantity = theForm.elements["AdultsParty"];
            var howmany = 0;

            if (quantity.value != "") {
                howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
            }
            return howmany;
        }


        function getTotal() {

            var HotelPrice = getHotelPrice() + LocalExtra() + FlyDriveExtra() + BalconyExtra() + getNights() + getAdults();

            document.getElementById('TotalCost').innerHTML =
                                              "Total Price For Hotel £" + HotelPrice;                        
        }
    }
```

Comment: Explain the business' rules better, please.

Comment: Also, create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) next time. It saves us a lot of time.

Comment: My apologies, still pretty new to all this, cheers for the heads up though.  Will post all the code on JSFIDDLE.

Comment: And the business rules are basically: I have 3 hotels, 1st is £50, 2nd is £75 and 3rd is £100.  Once the user picks a hotel using a radio box, the user then chooses what extras to have which there are 3 to choose from - localTourism = £60 FlyDrive = £45 Balcony = £30 using the check boxes.  Next using textboxes, the user inputs the number of adults and the number of nights to stay at the hotel.  This is all then calculated together to give the user the total cost.

Comment: @abhitalks - I didn't know what forms did when I wrote the html at the time but would it work to just have 1 form for a simple calculation for this?

Comment: @callum: For this simple calc, yes one form. In real life, it depends. Typically if you have multiple action points you may be better of with multiple forms. Also, note that some server-side frameworks like ASP.Net WebForms may restrict you to one form.

Comment: Ok thank you for the advice, will make some adjustments on the html and java tonight.

Comment: @Callum javaSCRIPT. People are gonna throw rocks at you for confusing those two lol.

Comment: @cr0ss Haha yeh my bad, didnt bother to proof read what I wrote,  riot shield is ready and waiting